# Error when building singed apk, No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: java, android, android-build

I'm trying to get my app published. So I create a singed APK in Android Studio.

by build >> Generate singed APK >> Fill in all the forms and start building.

But then it craches with some error. Already tried to remove the code but then I get new errors on some part of the code. So I think it's more difficult than just comment out the code.

Strange part of this question, when I just build the apk. of run the app directly on the phone. It doesn't give an error at all.

dexOptins is in there because first normal build gave java out of memeory exception. Already tried for compileSDKVersion 23 and buildtoolversion 23.0.0 but didn't do anything.

Here the files and the errors:

The error:

```
        Error:(1264, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorBackground'.
Error:(1265, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorTintedBackground'.
Error:(1271, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorBackground'.
Error:(1272, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorTintedBackground'.
Error:(1278, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorBackground'.
Error:(1279, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorTintedBackground'.
Error:(1286, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorBackground'.
Error:(1287, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorTintedBackground'.
Error:(1264, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorBackground'.
Error:(1265, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorTintedBackground'.
Error:(1271, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorBackground'.
Error:(1272, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorTintedBackground'.
Error:(1278, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorBackground'.
Error:(1279, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorTintedBackground'.
Error:(1286, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorBackground'.
Error:(1287, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorTintedBackground'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Part of code which gets the error

```
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
    <item name="colorTintedBackground">@color/colorTintedBackground</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkTheme_colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkTheme_colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/darkTheme_colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorBackground">@color/darkTheme_colorBackground</item>
    <item name="colorTintedBackground">@color/darkTheme_colorTintedBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Classic" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/classic_colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/classic_colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/classic_colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorBackground">@color/classic_colorBackground</item>
    <item name="colorTintedBackground">@color/classic_colorTintedBackground</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.Classic.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/classic_darkTheme_colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/classic_darkTheme_colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/classic_darkTheme_colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorBackground">@color/classic_darkTheme_colorBackground</item>
    <item name="colorTintedBackground">@color/classic_darkTheme_colorTintedBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoStatusBar" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.Classic" parent="AppTheme.Classic">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

//

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.Dark" parent="AppTheme.Dark">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.Classic.Dark" parent="AppTheme.Classic.Dark">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and the colors file:

```
            <color name="darkTheme_colorPrimary">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="darkTheme_colorPrimaryDark">#1E88E5</color>
    <color name="darkTheme_colorAccent">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="darkTheme_colorBackground">#303030</color>
    <color name="darkTheme_colorTintedBackground">#424242</color>

    <color name="classic_colorPrimary">#607d8b</color>
    <color name="classic_colorPrimaryDark">#455a64</color>
    <color name="classic_colorAccent">#455a64</color>
    <color name="classic_colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</color>
    <color name="classic_colorTintedBackground">#cdcdcd</color>

    <color name="classic_darkTheme_colorPrimary">#37474f</color>
    <color name="classic_darkTheme_colorPrimaryDark">#263238</color>
    <color name="classic_darkTheme_colorAccent">#90a4ae</color>
    <color name="classic_darkTheme_colorBackground">#303030</color>
    <color name="classic_darkTheme_colorTintedBackground">#263238</color>

        <color name="darkTheme_colorPrimary">#2196F3</color>
<color name="darkTheme_colorPrimaryDark">#1E88E5</color>
<color name="darkTheme_colorAccent">#2196F3</color>
<color name="darkTheme_colorBackground">#303030</color>
<color name="darkTheme_colorTintedBackground">#424242</color>
    <color name="classic_colorPrimary">#607d8b</color>
    <color name="classic_colorPrimaryDark">#455a64</color>
    <color name="classic_colorAccent">#455a64</color>
    <color name="classic_colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</color>
    <color name="classic_colorTintedBackground">#cdcdcd</color>
    <color name="classic_darkTheme_colorPrimary">#37474f</color>
    <color name="classic_darkTheme_colorPrimaryDark">#263238</color>
    <color name="classic_darkTheme_colorAccent">#90a4ae</color>
    <color name="classic_darkTheme_colorBackground">#303030</color>
    <color name="classic_darkTheme_colorTintedBackground">#263238</color>
```

build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.*********"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds true
        abortOnError false
        xmlReport true
        htmlReport true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile 'com.survivingwithandroid:weatherlib:1.4.0'
    //compile 'com.survivingwithandroid:weatherlib_volleyclient:1.4.0'
    compile files('libs/CircleImageView-master/CircleImageView-master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar')
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.apps.dashclock:dashclock-api:+'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1'
    compile 'com.diogobernardino:williamchart:2.2'
    compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'

    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Edit; I dit tried changing

```
<item name="colorBackground">@color/darkTheme_colorBackground</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/darkTheme_colorBackground</item>
```

This resolves all the colorbackground errors. but not the colortintedbackground errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by updating the build.gradle to the latest version like you have your dependencies. These are out dated.

```
 compileSdkversion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
```

Comment: Just for fun will you change everything in the build.gradle to version 22 and then copy the logcat and share.

Comment: It gives serious errors everywhere. values-v23 file and so on. Just for the fun ? or serious idea? in that case I can try to solve them

Comment: btw, when is was trying a lot. I fixed part of the erros by changing     `<item name="colorBackground">@color/classic_colorBackground</item>`
to     `<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/classic_colorBackground</item>`

But this trick didn't work for colorTintedBackground. So then I removed it

Comment: I was having problems updating Android versions yesterday and that fixed my problem. I didn't mean to give you the impression it was for fun, just a saying.

Comment: I think i fixed it. Well not fixed it, found out a work around. Will Post it as answer the next days. Thanks for helping around!